# How to set Uppercase key value in dotnet Core web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

i want to change : name, address, phone, city, province to set Uppercase

```
"status": 1,
"message": "OK",
"data": [
    {
        "name": "bigboss",
        "address": "alamanya big boss",
        "phone": "0582940298520",
        "city": "sby",
        "province": "jatim"
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with ASP.NET. Just use the JSON library of your choice to read the document and write it out again with uppercase keys. Perhaps the question is how to handle lowercase input? Or *produce* uppercase output? That's completely different and essentially asks how to configure the case names for whatever JSON library you use - JSON.NET or System.Text.Json.

Comment: thnks mr, for the answer, thats i mean,  i make my code to return the json data like thats, my code in c# dotnet core. 
like this :


return OK(new {
name = valuename,
email = valueemail
});

i want to change to uptercase to show in my json data

Comment: Which .NET Core version? .NET Core up to 2.2 uses JSON.NET, .NET Core 3 uses a new serializer. Do you want this for all classes or just a few? BTW there are many duplicates about this. You'll have to decide what you want to search for them though, eg `Return all objects as uppercase` or `return some properties as uppercase`. The answer in the first case is a serialization setting, in the second, JSON serialization attributes on the properties themselves

Comment: dotnet version is : 2.2.106

Comment: var list = await _repo.GetDataResult(parameters); 
                return Ok (new {
                        status = 1,
                            message = "OK",
                           data = list
                    });

Comment: Why do you use *lower*case names when you want *upper*case?

Comment: i want to make thats is uppercase.
  the code not impact if i use uppercase like that:
return OK(new{  NAME = valuename, EMAIL = valuename  });

thats API will i publish and some people use this with Uppercase Key.
thanks Mr @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

To change the values to uppercase in the given JSON data, you can follow these:

- Deserialize the JSON data
- ForEach in the JSON structure to find the properties you want to modify
- Convert the values to uppercase
- Serialize the modified JSON data back to its original format

```
string jsonData = yourExampleJsonData;
    
// Deserialize the JSON data into a ResponseData object
ResponseData response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseData>(jsonData);
    
// Convert the desired fields to uppercase
foreach (var item in response.data)
    {
        item.name = item.name.ToUpper();
        // Add others
    }

// Serialize the modified data back to JSON
string modifiedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true // For pretty-printing the JSON
    });

// Print the modified JSON
Console.WriteLine(modifiedJson);
```